# awk: String Concat adds "0"

Tags: string, awk, string-concatenation, concatenation

I tried to concatenate two strings in an awk-script but the result I got has a "0" at the last position.

```
    (input...) | awk '$1 ~ "match" { 
            (...)
            STRING1 = $2 ;
            STRING2 = $3 ;

            RESULT = STRING1 "" STRING2 ;   

            print RESULT ;   

    }' | (output....)
```

If e.g. `$2 = "Foo"` and `$3 = "Bla"`, RESULT will be "`FooBla0`".

How can I concatenate those two strings that the RESULT is "`FooBla`"?

Comment: Something must be missing, as a parallel example like `echo "hi" "he" "hi" | awk '$1 ~ "hi" {a=$2;b=$3; ab=a " " b; print ab }'` is working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code as given does not append a `0` to the line either your code is incomplete, your input is not as you expected or in your simplification of the problem you have left out a crucial piece of information:

```
$ cat file
match foo bla

$ awk '$1 ~ "match" { 
             STRING1 = $2 ;
             STRING2 = $3 ;

             RESULT = STRING1 "" STRING2 ;

             print RESULT ;   

     }' file
foobla
```

Note: that is a lot of unnecessary code for a simple field concatenation:

```
$ awk '$1=="match"{print $2$3}' file
foobla
```

Also be aware of the difference between `$1=="match"` and `$1~"match"`  the first is full field string match the second is a regex match. If you really wanted the second I suggest using `$1~/match/`.

---

As I suspected you missed out there crucial piece of information, `print fflush()` prints the exit status of the function. You want `print RESULT;fflush()` or better yet just put the function call on the next line of script.

Comment: Thanks for your help.
Yes, I tried it a few times, in some programs it worked — and in some not. ;)
But now I found my mistake: "print RESULT" worked – but I had "print RESULT fflush()", the "0" was there because of the "fflush()" ...

I know that for this little example my awk-Statement contains a lot of
unnecessairy code, but the whole statement has more then 20 lines, so I 
need this ;-)